# Linq Order list within a list based on parent Id

Tags: asp.net, linq

Having a list of items I need to sort/order items within that list based on outter list's id

```
public class Venue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Machines> Machines { get; set; }
}

public class Machine
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose I have a list of 3 venues and I want to sort only Venue's Machines where Venue.Id = 1;
Having a list of venues, I want to always sort by Venue Code, THEN sort machines by Name of Venue with Id = 1;

I tried this but doesn't work correctly:

```
 query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Code).ThenBy(y => y.Machines.OrderBy(q => q.Name).Where(x => y.Id == 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort a property  of an object which is an `IEnumerable<T>` you need to select a new:

```
query = query
    .Select(v => new Venue
    { 
        Id = v.Id, 
        Code = v.Code, 
        Machines = v.Id == 1 ? v.Machines.OrderBy(m => m.Name) : v.Machines
    })
    .OrderBy(v => v.Code);
```

Comment: this is correct except: Machines = v.Id == 1 ? v.Machines : v.Machines.OrderBy(m => m.Name) SHOULD be Machines = v.Id == 1 ? v.Machines.OrderBy(m => m.Name) : v.Machines

Comment: @ShaneKm: of course, or change `v.Id == 1` to `v.Id != 1` ;-)